# Como inserir o tamanho de uma matriz conforme entrada do usuário?

Tags: java, array

Como eu insiro, pedindo ao usuário através da classe `Scanner`, o tamanho da matriz e ele me informa os números de colunas e linhas que deseja, e depois imprimir os valores, sem utilizar métodos? Eu tentei mas está dando erro:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matriz {
    int matriz[][], linha, coluna;

    public Matriz(int linha, int coluna){
        matriz = new int [linha][coluna];
        this.linha = linha;
        this.coluna = coluna;
    }

    public void Inserir(){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int x=0; x < linha; x++){
            for(int y=0; y < coluna; y++){
                System.out.println("matriz ["+x+"]["+y+"] =");
                matriz[x][y]= entrada.nextInt();
            }//fim for
        }//fim for
    }//fim inserir

    public void Imprimir(){
        for(int x=0; x < linha; x++){

            for(int y=0; y < coluna; y++){
                System.out.print(matriz[x][y]+"\t");
            }//fim for
            System.out.println();//apenas para quebrar linha
        }//fim for
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int linha=0, coluna =0;

        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de linhas da matriz");
        linha = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de colunas da matriz");
        coluna = entrada.nextInt();
        Matriz mat = new Matriz(linha, coluna);

        mat.Inserir();
        mat.Imprimir();
    }
}
```

Sem utilizar métodos.

Comment: Qual erro? Tente melhorar sua pergunta?

Comment: Não consigo digitar numeros.

Comment: VOcê quer que o usuario informe o tamanho da matriz, e depois inicia-la com o tamanho informado? Edite a pergunta, não está nada claro o problema.

Comment: Sim, como nesse código http://pastebin.com/vp5sFiXC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após instanciar um array, você não pode mais alterar seu tamanho. Se precisa definir este tamanho após entrada de dados do usuários, apenas inicialize o array, instanciando posteriormente as entradas de dados necessárias:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        int matriz[][];

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int linha=0, coluna =0;

        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de linhas da matriz");
        linha = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de colunas da matriz");
        coluna = entrada.nextInt();

        matriz = new int[linha][coluna];

         for(int x=0; x < linha; x++){
            for(int y=0; y < coluna; y++){
                System.out.println("matriz ["+x+"]["+y+"] =");
                matriz[x][y]= entrada.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int x=0; x < linha; x++){

            for(int y=0; y < coluna; y++){
                System.out.print(matriz[x][y]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/jbSMy5)**

Dessa forma, o array será criado conforme o total de linhas/colunas informados via entrada de dados.

Comment: Sim, assim mesmo!